# Can I set the loading order of processes in launchctl

Tags: mysql, macos, nginx, launchctl

This relates to an OSX local server development environment using nginx, mysql and php.

Problem:

1. Each reboot OSX loads nginx and mysql using launchctl.
2. On reboot, nginx loads **before** mysql creating an error when my browser re-opens (mysql is not available so nginx can't open dynamic pages which were open when the last reboot commenced)

Question:
Is there a way to load mysql BEFORE nginx using launchctl?